# Azure search or full text index?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

Data in sql azure, we have an existing webapi expose the data with odata. Issue is client want to make a call with filters with substring query on a few columns, which making performance really slow. we are debating at this point whether to use full text search index or use the azure search service, thoughts please?

Comment: you can test both and see which offers better performance for your scenario,but i see Azure search more powerfull :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search

Comment: thanks, would azure search support logical multi-column substring filter? e.g. substringof('Alfreds', CompanyName) or substringof('adam', Name) or substringof('manager', title)?

Comment: I never tried,but it seems to be more powerfull based on the docs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of the considerations and tradeoffs between hosting search in Azure Search vs. using SQL Server FTS are captured [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search#how-it-compares).

As pointed out above, Azure Search can index in-database data - see [Connecting Azure SQL Database to Azure Search using indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers).

Answer (score 4):

You can point Azure Search at your AzureSQL database and it will index it without you having to write code, but Azure Search is a service you have to pay for on hourly basis and you can learn more information about it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/search/).

Azure Search is recommended for performing searches on various sources and application

Azure search can be used instead of Full-Text search, but If you need to join search results with other tables, then Full-Text Search is recommended.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, would azure search support logical multi-column on same table substring filter? e.g. substringof('Alfreds', CompanyName) or substringof('adam', Name) or substringof('manager', title)?

Comment: To my knowledge, Azure Search does not support partial matching other than prefix matching. More about it on this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Simple-query-syntax-in-Azure-Search?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I thought it support contains, but with my 2 minute poke around it does appears search only support prefix, e.g. Home* work, but *home* returns nothing, or am I missing anything, this is just sad, is not full text search anyhow

Comment: As I mentioned, my experience it works as prefix matching only. One more thing I would like to suggest you since it seems you will choose -Full-Text Search. Scale up the SQL Azure tier before creating full-text indexes, once they have been created scale down.

Comment: Azure Search supports regex searches on multiple fields (using [Lucene query syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search)), as well running searches as part of a filter (OData $filter expression) - see [search.ismatch function](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search). For more general tradeoffs between SQL FTS and Azure Search, see my response.